# Same width for tabs in TabPageIndicator

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I am using TabPageIndicator. I have four tabs in it. each tab has differnt width by default. but i need each tab having the same width. how to acheive this.

Currently i am getting the following output.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are supporting API level greater than equal to 11 then you can use `Fixed Tabs + Swipe` or `Scrollable Tabs + Swipe` for same size tabs which uses `ViewPager` or you can use `TabHost` which can be used on API level below 11. You can get an implementation of this by creating a new `Activity`in Eclipse by selecting 
Navigation Type options as shown below:

[image: Navigation type options]